# Pencilblue installation

Tags: mongodb, mean.io, pencilblue

I am pretty new to mean stack development, but would like to learn. While trying to run pencilblue using pbctrl start, I get following error:

**Error message**

```
Override file [/Users/Illusion/peter/config.js] will be applied.
2015-10-12T12:36:29.683Z - info: [M] SystemStartup: Log Level is: info
2015-10-12T12:36:29.992Z - info: [M] System[M]: 1 workers spawned. Listening for disconnects.
Override file [/Users/Illusion/peter/config.js] will be applied.
2015-10-12T12:36:30.231Z - info: [1] SystemStartup: Log Level is: info
/Users/Illusion/peter/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:228
        process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })
                                      ^

Error: MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017 - mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/pencilblue
Is your instance running?
    at /Users/Illusion/peter/include/dao/db_manager.js:84:31
    at /Users/Illusion/peter/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:236:20
    at /Users/Illusion/peter/node_modules/mongodb/lib/db.js:203:14
    at null.<anonymous> (/Users/Illusion/peter/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:226:9)
    at g (events.js:260:16)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at emit (events.js:172:7)
    at null.<anonymous> (/Users/Illusion/peter/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:255:68)
    at g (events.js:260:16)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
Override file [/Users/Illusion/peter/config.js] will be applied.
2015-10-12T12:36:30.900Z - info: [2] SystemStartup: Log Level is: info
/Users/Illusion/peter/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:228
        process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })
```

Can you please suggest what has been done wrong?

Comment: It looks like your MongoDB server isn't running. Also, this isn't a programming question, so it doesn't belong on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like MongoDB isn't running. `ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017` means that PencilBlue is trying to access MongoDB on localhost using port 27017. Ensure that MongoDB is running on that port and restart PencilBlue.